# Lord Krishna and Lord Shiva in Brahma Vaivarta Purana?

Tags: scripture, shiva, krishna, brahma-vaivarta-purana

Hare Krishna

I have read somewhere verses from Brahma Vaivarta Purana in which Lord Krishna says to Lord Shiva like you are dearest one.

What is exact verse and from which chapter of Brahma Vaivarta Purana which says that? Can you explain event of pastimes related to it?

Om Namah Shivaya
Jay Shri Krishna

Answer (score 2):

There are Multiple Instance Of Krishna Saying That to Shiva In the Brahma Vaivarta.

> **Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Brahma Khanda Chapter 6**

[image]

(Krishna says this to Shiva)

> **Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Krishna Janma Khanda , Chapter 36**

[image]
[image]

(Krishna Says this to Radharani)